# I would like to know the translation of the writings on an ancient seal, to English, please

Tags: translation, seal

The seal representing an imperial lion in red porfid, has two scripts.

1. On the lateral of the base, two colons (XVI-XVII Chinese Characters). My research helped by one chinese friend say that it says "Year of the Dragon, Hu Zhengyan". Famous printer, artist and seals carver 1584-1674. 庚辰年（龙年）胡正言.I would like confirmation.

Please find attached one[image: seal base inscription] picture took from the seal.

Thank you very much in advance.
Aurelio

Comment: It is indeed 庚辰年 胡正言

Comment: supposed the seal is not fake, the “庚辰年” should be interpreted as 1640. because during mr 胡’s life, it’s the only match.

Comment: Thank you very much it has been very useful.

Answer (score 1):

"胡正言" should refer to the [Chinese artist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hu_Zhengyan). He was born in 1584 and died in 1674.

"庚辰年" is recorded by "干支纪年法 (The sexagenary cycle)", a cycle of sixty terms. You can check specific years at [庚辰年](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%9A%E8%BE%B0). Based on his profile we can deduce "庚辰年" here refers to 1640.